# Nested Has Many Through Simple Form Multi Selection Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, simple-form, has-many-through

I am having an issue with the create statement for an association I have. I have no problem with updates, but when I create a new object with the simple form association my validation on the through model screws everything up.

Form

```
%div.inner-padding
= simple_form_for(@group, :wrapper => :bootstrap3_horizontal, :html => { multipart: true, :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f|
  %section#group-show
    %div.panel
      %div
        = f.input :name
        = f.association :group_type, collection: current_user.organization.group_types.all, required: true unless current_user.organization.nil?
        = create_link(:group_type, 'Create a new group type')
        -if can? :access, @group, :organization
          = f.association :organization, required: true
      %div.group-users
        %div.group-users-header
          %h3 Users
          %hr
        %div
          = f.association :users, collection: current_user.organization.users.all, as: :check_boxes, label_method: :basic_info,
                          include_blank: false, label: false, class:'list-group-item' unless current_user.organization.nil?
```

Models

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group_type
  belongs_to :organization

  has_many :user_groups, inverse_of: :group

  has_many :users, through: :user_groups,
           :after_remove    => :alter_user,
           :after_add       => :alter_user,
           inverse_of: :groups

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_groups, allow_destroy: true
```

...

```
class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :process_expirations unless :skip_callbacks

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group,  -> { includes :training_types }

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

  # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
  # Validations
  # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

  validates :user_id,
            :group_id,
            :presence => true

  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :group_id

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify

  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable

  validates :password, :presence => true,
            :confirmation => true,
            :length => {:within => 6..40},
            :on => :create
  validates :password, :confirmation => true,
            :length => {:within => 6..40},
            :allow_blank => true,
            :on => :update

  # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
  # Relations
  # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :groups, through: :user_groups,
           :after_remove     => :alter_group,
           :after_add        => :alter_group,
           :dependent        => :destroy

  has_many :training_histories, -> { includes :lecture }

  has_many :training_types, through: :expirations,
           :after_remove             => :alter_training_type,
           :after_add                => :alter_training_type
```

Controller action

```
  def new
    @group = Group.new
    @group.user_groups.build.build_user
    add_breadcrumb 'new group', new_group_path
  end
```

The error I get is "user_groups.group_id"=>["can't be blank"] and I'm pretty sure it's caused by the validation in my user_groups model.

Any suggestions? I tried following the guide here:http://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through but they aren't really doing a multi select for their option. Not sure what direction to head here, it's weird that I don't have to change anything and it works for updates perfectly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

Inverse_of is a really weird thing that I didn't really understand apparently, but this is very valuable and powerful. Basically ActiveRecord doesn't understand that two objects reference each other. For example, if you have a relation that is 1-1 like so:

class Test
has_many :answers
end

class Answer
has_many :tests
end

Tests and Answers won't recognize without a db query that they reference the same things. Inverse of tells Rails they are without that. Cool stuff.

My solution was adding
has_many :user_groups, :inverse_of => :group

To Group

and

has_many :user_groups, :inverse_of => :user

To User and everything worked.

Magical.

Also removed the references to id on the user_group model to just validate the object presence.